# Htaccess 301 change old URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I would like change url in my htaccess and using redirect 301 for SEO.

my old url:

```
RewriteRule ^my-oldurl-(([0-9]+)-[a-zA-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?page=my-detail&id=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L]
```

my new url:

```
RewriteRule ^my-newurl-(([0-9]+)-[a-zA-z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?page=my-detail&id=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L]
```

My last test (error 500):

```
RewriteRule ^my-oldurl-(([0-9]+)-[a-zA-z0-9_-]+).html ^my-newurl-(([0-9]+)-[a-zA-z0-9_-]+).html [QSA,R=301]
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: what is the good writing for a redirect 301 ?

Comment: Can you provide a functional example of the old URL and the new URL?  the full http://www.example.com/... I'm not sure what you're doing with the $1 and $2 variables in this example (those would usually be URL path variables, but you don't seem to be using them like that)

Comment: my old url: http://example.com/my-oldurl-48-my-title-of-artcle.html and the new url http://example.com/my-newurl-48-my-title-of-artcle.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit fuzzy, but I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^my-oldurl-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php?page=my-detail&id=$1&cat=$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Or, if you prefer a 2 step approach you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^my-oldurl-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ my-newurl-$1-$2.html [QSA,L,R=301]
```

and rely on the already existing rewrite rule for the new urls.

---

Also note the backslash escaping (`\`) I added to the dot (`.`) in the regular expression. It works without, but this version is more precise.